# Javascript array alllocation

Tags: javascript

I was dealing with a problem and got to the point where I thought I could use the Ids to my entity instances as array indices for easy lookup.

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[obj.Id] = true;
```

Assume obj.Id is 1000 here, so will be myArray.length. Am I allocating 1000 bytes for a single boolean value here or is it just returning the maximum index as length?

Comment: Why not use a key value style object, `var myArray = {};
myArray[obj.Id] = true;`

Comment: it's "_returning the maximum index as length_", but sparse arrays slow down `[].map()` and `for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)`-style loops...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be allocating so many bytes.

But what you are really looking for is an key-value object like

```
var myObj = {};
myObj[obj.Id] = true;
//then to access
console.log(myObj[obj.Id])
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did use the object approach eventually. I was just interested to know if array space allocation is based on index.

Comment: And could you please explain why is using objects rather than array is a better approach then?